# Plunker can't find angularfire simpleLogin

Tags: angularjs, angularfire, plunker

I'm using Plunker to show a bit of Angular functionality.  I hit a really annoying bug that says:
`failed to instantiate module fireApp due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module simpleLogin due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'simpleLogin' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.`

I have tried to import simpleLogin in various ways 
`<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/simple-login/1.6.3/firebase-simple-login.js"></script>`

and

`<script data-require="firebase-simple-login@*" data-semver="1.6.2" src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/simple-login/1.6.2/firebase-simple-login.js"></script>`

Here's my head:

  `<head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.21/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.21" data-require="angular.js@1.2.21"></script>
    <script data-require="firebase@*" data-semver="1.0.18" src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.18/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.8.0/angularfire.js" data-semver="0.8.0" data-require="angularfire@*"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/simple-login/1.6.2/firebase-simple-login.js" data-semver="1.6.2" data-require="firebase-simple-login@*"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" data-semver="2.1.1" data-require="jquery@*"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" data-semver="3.1.1" data-require="bootstrap@*"></script>
    <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" data-semver="4.1.0" data-require="font-awesome@*" />
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
  </head>`

Here's the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/YX9qXmPCurZ6BEXCDilr?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

I forgot that I was using simpleLogin as a service (via angularfire seed).

To use it otherwise, you just need to use `$firebaseSimpleLogin` as a dependency in your controller.

[User Login and Authentication in Angularfire](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html)